# How to find the max of list in each cell of pandas in a performant way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'c1': ['a','b','c'],
        'c2': [[1,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,0]],
        'c3': [[(10,1),(20,2)],[(40, 4),(50,5),(60,6)],[(70,7),(80,8),(90,9),(0,0)]]
    }
)

    c1  c2              c3
0   a   [1, 2]          [(10, 1), (20, 2)]
1   b   [4, 5, 6]       [(40, 4), (50, 5), (60, 6)]
2   c   [7, 8, 9, 0]    [(70, 7), (80, 8), (90, 9), (0, 0)]
```

I would like to get max of each column in c3 based on the second element in the tuple.

```
    c1  c2              c3                                     maxi
0   a   [1, 2]          [(10, 1), (20, 2)]                     (20,2)
1   b   [4, 5, 6]       [(40, 4), (50, 5), (60, 6)]            (60,6)
2   c   [7, 8, 9, 0]    [(70, 7), (80, 8), (90, 9), (0, 0)]    (90,9)
```

I want this to be performative because I have 40k rows. So far I have reached with below solution but from a quick search, I could see people do not recommend using `apply` for performance reasons. Is there any other alternative which is performant?

```
df['maxi'] = df['c3'].apply(max, key= lambda v: v[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is fast (depends of length of each lit of tuples), faster is use `max(x,key=itemgetter(1))`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

#300k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


In [39]: %timeit [max(x, key=lambda y:y[1]) for x in df['c3']]
274 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [40]: %timeit df['c3'].apply(max, key= lambda v: v[1])
260 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [41]: %timeit df['c3'].apply(lambda x: max(x, key= lambda v: v[1]))
259 ms ± 2.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
In [42]: %timeit [max(x,key=itemgetter(1)) for x in df['c3']]
237 ms ± 25.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [43]: %timeit df['c3'].apply(lambda x: max(x,key=itemgetter(1)))
228 ms ± 16.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [44]: %timeit df['c3'].map(lambda x: max(x,key=itemgetter(1)))
214 ms ± 2.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [45]: %timeit df['c3'].apply(max, key=itemgetter(1))
199 ms ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```